# How to navigate href in anchor tag via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an easy way to have JavaScript mimic a User clicking an anchor tag on a page? That means the Referrer Url needs to be set. Just setting the document.location.href doesn't set the Referrer Url.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click();
});
</script>

<a href="http://example.com">Go here</a>
```

This doesn't work because there isn't a Click() event setup for the link.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do:

```
window.location = $("a").attr("href");
```

If you want to keep the referrer, you could do this:

```
var href = $('a').attr('href');
$('<form>').attr({action: href, method: 'GET'}).appendTo($('body')).submit();
```

It is hackish, but works in all browsers.

Comment: I don't think this works in order to get the Referrer Url. I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Mm. It does on Firefox, just not on IE. Looking into it.

Comment: You can just use window.location.assign() if you want to keep referrer url, so the code will then be window.location.assign("http://localhost/");

Answer (score 2):

```
document.location.href = "#wanted_Location";
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a").each(function(){
    if($(this).click()){
      document.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for because the Referrer Url doesn't get set. I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to achieve it,

**HTML**

```
<a href="https://getbootstrap.com/" id="fooLinkID">Bootstrap is life </a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Simulating click after 3 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('fooLinkID').click();
}, 3 * 1000);
```

Using plain javascript to simulate a click.

You can check working example here on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/onhje5o5/).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, referer doesn't get set using document.location (as per my other answer), might work with window.navigate(url)? If that doesn't work the following might, though it's quite - ehrm - ugly:

```
$(function() {
  $("a").each(function(){
    if($(this).click()){
      $('<form method="get" action="' + $(this).attr("href") + '"></form>').appendTo("body").submit();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```