# How to allow for <p> as clickable and use embedded <a> href?

Tags: html, css

I have the following p embedded with an a href.  How can I make the p clickable and use the internal a.href already defined?

```
<style type="text/css">
    p.button:hover { cursor: pointer; }
    p.padding  { padding-right:10px; padding-left:10px; }
 </style>
<table class="inline_button" style="width: auto ">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;  min-height: 28px;background-color: #fe9d39; line-height: 28px;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;padding: 0;border: 2px solid #fe9d39;">
             <div id="whatever">
            <p class="button padding" style="padding: ; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;" href="http://google.com">click me</a></p>
             </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Constraint**: no jquery or js (or any scripting)

Comment: put the <p> inside the <a>

Comment: @Placeholders_in_use: nice call on embedding the p!  worked great!

Comment: Please keep in mind, Adding P inside a tag not a semantic way. Because a tag is a inline element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use display:block; for anchor tag. also use padding for anchor tag instead of P tag, so it make clicked for your whole P tag. After above changes your code look like below.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    p.button:hover { cursor: pointer; }
    p.padding  { padding:0; margin:0;}
 </style>
<table class="inline_button" style="width: auto ">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;  min-height: 28px;background-color: #fe9d39; line-height: 28px;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;padding: 0;border: 2px solid #fe9d39;"><div id="whatever">
        <p class="button padding" style="padding: ; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; padding:5px 10px; display:block;" href="http://google.com">click me</a></p>
      </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `display: block` to your `<a>` so it fills the space within your `<p>`.

If you're using an HTML5 doctype (or aren't worried about validation and possible old IE errors) you can wrap the `p` within the `a` tag.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do what you want would be to add a click handler to the `<p>` element using jquery.

`$('p.button').click(function(){$(this).children('a').click()});`

A better/alternative way of thinking of it would be to put the `<p>` element into an anchor tag:

`<a href="someurl">
  <p>Some content</p>
</a>`

Comment: Note that your jQuery won't work. `.click()` will only call any event handlers attatched the the `a` tag. It wont actually navigate. See: http://jsfiddle.net/4deFN/. Tested with Firefox

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603556/how-to-navigate-href-in-anchor-tag-via-javascript) would fix it.